# How to align elements of two seperate ng-repeats in a table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-table

I have am repeating the elements of two arrays with two separate `ng-repeat`s. The elements of the first array are labels that correspond to a stat from the second array. I would like to display them in the same table so that the cells take up the widths of the elements from the first array are aligned with those from the second. Here is my attempt:

```
<table>         
        <tbody ng-repeat="data in pTab track by $index" class="headerWrapper" ng-if="modelIsActive2( data, $index)">
            <tr class="specHeaders" ng-repeat="headers in data.modelHeaders" ng-if="!$last">
                <td class="specs2">{{headers}}</td>
            </tr>                                                               
        </tbody>

        <tbody ng-repeat="data in pTab track by $index" class="specsWrapper" ng-if="modelIsActive2(data, $index)">      
            <tr class="specsWrapper" ng-repeat="modelArrays in data.modelData" ng-if="modelIsActive(modelArrays, $index)">
                <td class="specNumbers" ng-repeat="mod in modelArrays track by $index" ng-if="!$last">
                    <p class="specValues2">{{mod}}</p>
                </td>
            </tr>                                                                   
        </tbody>
</table>
```

However, this doesn't appear to format them like a table with aligned columns. Here is my output:

[image: screenshot of output]

I removed also removed all classes in case the CSS was affecting the alignment but that didn't help. I'm guessing it's something to do with my multiple repeats?

How can I align these rows properly?

I also tried with a `<theader>` tag in place of the first `<tbody>` tag.

Thank you very much for your time.

EDIT:
Trying przno's method. I need these nested repeats to get to the content I want. Not sure how to make this work:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <div ng-repeat="data in pTab track by $index" class="headerWrapper" ng-if="modelIsActive2( data, $index)">
                <div class="specHeaders" ng-repeat="headers in data.modelHeaders" ng-if="!$last">
                    <th class="specs2">{{headers}}</th>
                </div>                                                              
            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <div ng-repeat="data in pTab track by $index" class="specsWrapper" ng-if="modelIsActive2(data, $index)">        
                <div class="specsWrapper" ng-repeat="modelArrays in data.modelData" ng-if="modelIsActive(modelArrays, $index)">
                    <div class="specNumbers" ng-repeat="mod in modelArrays track by $index" ng-if="!$last">
                        <td class="specValues2">{{mod}}</td>
                    </div>
                </div>                                                                  
            </div>
        </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is a simplified version of my issue in a plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/LpvuIjEKvJ2MLzPfFrfo?p=preview

**EDIT 3**

Here's how the data used in the example looks like:

```
$scope.pTab = {
  data: {
    modelHeaders: ["specHeader1", "specHeader2", "specHeader3", "specHeader4"],
    modelData: {
      modelArray: ["spec1", "spec2", "spec3", "spec4"]
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: In the first case, shouldn't you be `ng-repeat`ing the `<td>`, not `<tr>`? Seeing sample data might help

Comment: Can you put this into a plnkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: Everything displayed in the output is dynamically created by the app based on some local files so it's a bit hard to show the data without over complicating things. Definitely couldn't get it in a plnkr. I'll try to come up with something. Sorry about this, I figured this might be an issue with me asking about this problem. Thanks for looking though! I'll try to get a better explanation/update out. May not be able to until tomorrow however.

Comment: @NicholasSmith
Here is an example of my issue in a plunker. Thanks for the help!

http://plnkr.co/edit/LpvuIjEKvJ2MLzPfFrfo?p=preview

Comment: @NewDev here is a plunker with some sample data:

http://plnkr.co/edit/LpvuIjEKvJ2MLzPfFrfo?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this plnkr, I think it's showing what you want.

http://plnkr.co/edit/h9z5airokWFV5oxWt73z?p=preview

html:

```
   <div ng-repeat="data in pTab">

      <table>

        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="headers in data.modelHeaders">{{headers}}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="modelArrays in data.modelData">
            <td ng-repeat="specs in modelArrays">{{specs}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

      </table>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data object in question is exactly how it looks like, then you could just iterate over the inner `modelHeaders` array for `<th>` and iterate over `modelData.modelArray` - for `<td>`:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="header in pTab.data.modelHeaders">{{header}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="data in pTab.data.modelData>
    <td ng-repeat="spec in data.modelArray">{{spec}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If, however, you have more properties under `pTab`, or under `modelData` - or, in others, your model is nested - then you'd need to flatten it first for View representation.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately there are more properties under pTab and modelData.

Comment: @user95227, And you want to flatten the structure and create columns in the same table for all?

Comment: I've created a new plunker to better illustrate my actual data here: 

http://plnkr.co/edit/3k6Ew5YWFQhDw77UpSB8?p=preview

The `$first` filters are just a placeholder for functions I have that selects the proper array to display the contents of (and the proper headers). So there will only ever be one row of specs and one row of headers. Does that make sense? Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question, the solution is simple:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- declaring arrays here for demo purpose -->
<table ng-app ng-init="array1 = ['some', 'headers', 'for', 'table']; array2 = ['here', 'are', 'some', 'data'];" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="header in array1">{{header}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="data in array2">{{data}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But be aware that your arrays should contain same number of items, if not it will be of course mis-aligned.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! However I need the nested repeats to get access to the contents of the arrays I want to display. I made an edit with my attempt based on what your demo shows. I take it I can't just throw all the divs inside the <tr> with the <td>'s around my data? Thanks again. Sorry that my situation is specific and not simple